# Multiple Resources in "Assigned To" column

Tags: tfs, project-management

In TFS 2010, how can I assign multiple resources to a particular Task? The "Assigned To" column has a dropdown. Can it be configured or modified to have a multi-checkbox instead?

In Microsoft Project, I'm able to assign multiple names to a task, but could not sync same to TFS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at the community custom work item control on codeplex => http://witcustomcontrols.codeplex.com/. There is a multi value selector control already present => http://witcustomcontrols.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Multivalue%20control&referringTitle=Home.

HTH
Cheers, Tarun